# Warning! PATH is not properly set up, usually this is caused by shell initialization files

Tags: ruby, rvm

Whenever I go to a folder with a `.rvmrc` file, there is a warning:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin' is not available,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         to fix run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247'.
```

I did `rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247`, but the warning is still present.

**Note**: There are no errors, Im able to run my application just fine, but the warning is very annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/me/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Comment: I met the same problem and by printing of `$PATH`, it all becomes clear that heroku's `toolbelt` somehow goes before `ruby`. Change it back solved my problem. Thanks @AndrewMarshall

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a bug and was handled with https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2050 and was released as rvm stable `1.21.15` at 2013-07-29 19:15:30 -0700

Comment: I am getting this with 1.21.15. this is my path `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/pills/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/pills/.rvm/bin` I had two ruby version managers.

Comment: you need to actually read the message, in your case rbenv is first in PATH before RVM - which basically transfers control to rbenv, sometimes it is enough to just run: `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles`

Answer (score 144):

I was getting the same warning even after upgrading RVM to version 1.25.16. I was able to fix the warning by running:

```
rvm reset
```

Then when I ran:

```
rvm version
```

I did not receive the error anymore.

Comment: RVM reset worked for me, while the stated answer didn't!

Comment: Worked for me on 2.2.0

Comment: Also worked for me. I even tried updating RVM and it would clear the error until I restarted Terminal. Doing your suggestion fixed it perpetually. Thank you! It was quite annoying.

Comment: It worked for me, but when I restarted the terminal it appeared again.

Answer (score 29):

If you know what you're doing, and your `PATH` is set to what you want, you can suppress this message by putting the following in your `~/.rvmrc`:

```
rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1
```

This is handy if you use other path-manipulating programs like virtualenv, or if you just want to prefix your path with `~/bin` or something.

Comment: I was looking for this is the docs but did see it. Did you discover from source or elsewhere?

Comment: I found it in the source after getting sick of seeing it. There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2050) discussing it, but as far as I know they haven't bothered documenting it or fixing the warning message.

Comment: Nice find Jim Stewart

Comment: This removes the ugly warning. I wish i could vote thousands!

Answer (score 14):

I was able to get rid of this by doing

```
rvm get head
```

Comment: `rvm get stable` will also work and is preferred over getting head.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, For some reason, the warning was still present after doing `rvm get stable`.

Comment: I got same problem after doing `rvm get stable` or `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles` any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem too, and `rvm get head` didn't work for me, finally it was solved by running `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles`, then restarted the terminal and the annoying warning message disappeared! And the solution is found here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2074
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

`rvm get stable` solved this for me

(as pointed out in comments on another answer by AndrewMarshall)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I ran an `export PATH` command without realizing the implications and ran into the identical error, but I also lost all control of my typical commands like cd and pwd. I didn't want to reset the rvm tools I'd already installed per some of the answers above.

First attempt was to some sort of mac default path (found on google):

```
$ export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

Which actually solved my first problem of not having access to my typical command line tools, but was still getting the same error as @Santosh's initial problem. The next thing I did was navigate to my directory where I've set up rvm to start, and then to run a new export command as follows:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH"
```

This was how I initially set up rvm, and no more errors. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin' is not at first place,
usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.1'.

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

**Next you might get below Error:**

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with ‘rvm use …’ will not work.
You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use /bin/bash --login as the command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add the following at the end of your
`~/.bash_profile` OR `~/.zshrc` file.

In this example our ruby version is `ruby-2.6.1`. Replace this with your ruby version.

```
export PATH=~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin:$PATH

# RVM manual script for loading rvm to shell
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Temporarily solution

I solved it temporarily by running `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` it is the only solution it worked for me. but you have to run it every time you close the terminal. at least solves your emergency