# Issue with Deploying a Rails app on VPS - cannot load such file -- unicorn/launcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I am trying to deploy my rails application to a digitalocean VPS droplet. I have the following setup Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 12.10 (Nginx + Unicorn). I have installed Ruby ruby-2.0.0-p247 and rails Rails 4.0.0 via rvm but when I try to restart Unicorn I get the following error.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/
  core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in 
    `require': cannot load such file -- unicorn/launcher (LoadError)

from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/
  core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in 
    `require' from /usr/bin/unicorn:3:in `<main>'
```

Could it be because if my GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH are different?

```
$GEM_PATH:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global

$GEM_HOME:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

Comment: No, GEM_HOME only tells `gem install` where to put new gems. GEM_PATH tells Rubygems where to find gems. So next question becomes: did you install unicorn somewhere in your GEM_PATH?

Comment: Yep looks like unicorn-4.6.3 is in the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems folder

Comment: Your `PATH` is not set up properly. You're running the unicorn binary from `/usr/bin` (see error message). You should be running it from the rvm bin directory. Make sure rvm is set up correctly (you are running the rvm init scripts), and that `PATH` contains the rvm bin directory before anything else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19189111/823617

Comment: @Casper that was it! thank you so much! please place the answer below so you get the cred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PATH` is not set up properly. You're running the unicorn binary from `/usr/bin` (see error message). You should be running it from the rvm bin directory. Make sure rvm is set up correctly (you are running the rvm init scripts), and that `PATH` contains the rvm bin directory before anything else.

See here for some further discussion on rvm and `PATH` for a similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189111/823617