# RVM Warning! PATH is not properly set up

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, rubygems, rvm

I just installed rvm on my mac, but I receive this warning on global commands

> Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin' is not at first place, usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries, it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles', to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194'.

My $PATHS confirms the warning:

```
$echo :$PATH:
```

> /usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:

As suggested, I first tried `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` to no avail, then I checked my shell initializations files. My /.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt
```

My /Users/User/.bash_profile seems to be the culprit:

```
export PS1="[\w]$"
alias ll='ls -laGH'
alias .='echo $PWD'

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

# rvm
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

The reason is if I remove Heroku Toolbelt and the rvm paths (which were answers suggested by other stack overflow questions), `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin` would be in first place and the problem is resolved. However, I don't know what to do with the Heroku Toolbelt. Additionally, shouldn't `PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH` place rvm first anyways?

I must be missing some trivial solution.

Additional notes:
`$rvm --debug get head` produces no installation notes regarding this except for the warning posted above.

Update: calling `rvm system` fixes the problem, but only in the current shell session. `$echo $PATH` now produces:

```
:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:
```

What is a permanent fix?

Comment: The RVM initialization needs to be the **last line** in your `.bashrc`, it should not be in your `.bash_profile`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276701/getting-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-when-doing-rvm-use-2-0-0-defaul

Comment: Also read this http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment to understand the difference between `bash_profile` and `bashrc` and how to set them up properly.

Comment: @Casper, thank you for the articles. I have read and followed the instructions outlined, learning immensely from it. I also realized my system ruby was 1.9.3 instead of the current 2.2. The issue was fixed after `rvm use ruby-head`, along with the .bash_profile changes. Turns out the solution was trivial.

Answer (score 64):

I have the same problem with rvm 1.25.26.

### solution:

I've modified `~/.bashrc` as follows:

```
## rvm
PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[ -s ${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm ] && source ${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

### causing:

Warning is fired at __rvm_path_match_gem_home_check() function in 
`$HOME/.rvm/scripts/functions/cli`.

If the beginning of `$PATH` does not start from `$GEM_HOME/bin`, a warning message is displayed.

```
__rvm_path_match_gem_home_check()
{
  (( ${rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag:-0} == 0 )) || return 0
  [[ -n "${GEM_HOME:-}" ]] || return 0
  case "$PATH:" in
    ($GEM_HOME/bin:*) true ;; # all fine here
    (*:$GEM_HOME/bin:*)
      __rvm_path_match_gem_home_check_warning "is not at first place"
      ;;
    (*)
      __rvm_path_match_gem_home_check_warning "is not available"
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: holy heck u rock! This also helped! http://qiita.com/900090009/items/779dd0b5317e24939489

Comment: there should be a PR for this

Answer (score 16):

In my case, Heroku had added the following to my .bashrc:

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

Notice how it's prepending itself to the path. All I had to do was switch it around to:

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/heroku/bin"
```

And my problem was solved!

If you don't have Heroku, look for anything else that may be prepending itself to your path. Really, RVM just wants to make sure it has a fair chance to load Ruby before any gems that include themselves in the path get loaded.

Answer (score 5):

The solution was to run

```
$rvm install ruby-head
$rvm use ruby-head
```

with an optional `$rvm docs generate-ti`

I was using an outdated version of Ruby on my system, updating it to the current version fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Search your config files for:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

Replace that line with:

`export PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

To make sure the RVM code is at the start of your $PATH. Also make sure no other code puts itself at the start of $PATH.

Answer (score 3):

Because I was using the ubuntu version of rvm, I needed to put this in my .profile:

```
PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin:$PATH" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[ -s /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm ] && source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem in Ubuntu 18.04 by commenting

> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

in **~/.bashrc** file, as the same line was there in **~/.bash_profile** file.

Answer (score 1):

Right. I'dumping this answer as I spent hours researching with no success. I hope this will save someone else some time.

My problem was having 2 ruby heads installed and apparently, the ruby version was also an issue.

```
➜ rvm list                   
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/ma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin' is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for 'PATH=...' entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles'.
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.8.7-head'.
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.8.7-head [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-head [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

In this case, (trying all the above solutions, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276701/getting-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-when-doing-rvm-use-2-0-0-defaul) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968580/warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-usually-this-is-caused-by-shell-initializa)) setting my default to `ruby-head [ x86_64 ]` and restarting the terminal the `Warning!` AND my current ruby version was persisting as the above snippet shows.

To fix that:

`rvm remove ruby-1.8.7-head`

Now, if I restart the terminal:

```
➜ rvm list                  

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-head [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, and the end of .bashrc, you need to guarantee the rvm path is at the beginning of `$PATH`