# "Warning! PATH is not properly set up" & "RVM is not a function" after Heroku toolbelt installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rvm, heroku-toolbelt

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
I installed rvm + ruby + rails and restarted the machine. 
Everything was working fine until I installed the Heroku toolbet.

When I decided to create a new project-specific gemset with `rvm use ruby-2.2.1@new_app --ruby-version --create`, I received this message:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin' is not at first place,
usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.1'.

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use /bin/bash --login as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
```

I receive the "Warning! PATH is not properly set up" warning every time I use a rvm command, such as `rvm list` for instance.

The output of `echo $PATH` is:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/mark/.rvm/bin:/home/mark/.rvm/bin:/home/mark/.rvm/bin:/home/mark/.rvm/bin
```

As you can see `/usr/local/heroku/bin` is at first place instead of `/home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin`, and this is probably causing the issue. 
I suppose it would be better if `/usr/local/heroku/bin` were after all the rvm paths.

My `.bash_profile` looks fine:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

The last lines of my `.bashrc` file are:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

I tried to run `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` (and `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles` as suggested in [Warning! PATH is not properly set up, usually this is caused by shell initialization files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968580/warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-usually-this-is-caused-by-shell-initializa)) without results.

I would change the order of the paths in `$PATH` and move Heroku to a more convenient place if possible and if I knew how to do it.
What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Cullum's solution in [RVM Warning! PATH is not properly set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650731/rvm-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up) solved my issue. 
 It seems also that for `rvm` to work properly it is necessary that the respective line of code in `~/bashrc` be the last.