# Install ruby 2.4.0 - Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated

Tags: ruby, rvm

I need to update some of Rails gems and their newer versions require ruby 2.4.0. My current version is 2.3.3, so I am trying to install a new ruby version.

`rvm install 2.4.2` returns this error:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.3'.
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.9-next', you are using older version '1.28.0'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.15/x86_64/ruby-2.4.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system....................................................................|
Installing required custom packages: homebrew/dupes homebrew/dupes.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_install_custom homebrew/dupes homebrew/dupes',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/adam/.rvm/log/1584798412_ruby-2.4.2/install_custom.log
    do
        brew tap "${__tap}" || return $?;
    done
}
GEM_HOME=/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
PATH=/Users/adam/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/bin:/Users/adam/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3:/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global
command(3): requirements_osx_brew_install_custom homebrew/dupes homebrew/dupes
++ typeset __tap
++ for __tap in '"$@"'
++ brew tap homebrew/dupes
Updating Homebrew...
Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: You can look at the questions that have already been answered on the site  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650731/rvm-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RVM Warning! PATH is not properly set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650731/rvm-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up)