# Cannot install Pods in iOS Project

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, cocoapods

I have been trying to update cocoapod. In between I have updated Ruby and RVM. Now when I try `pod init` in my new ios project, shows the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
2: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I checked the following,

1. `ruby --version`

   ```
   ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin16]
   ```
2. `rvm list rubies`

   ```
   =* ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]

   # => - current
   # =* - current && default
   #  * - default
   ```

Comment: try to reinstall cocoda pods:
$ sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: @AndreiDurnea Thanks for the fast reply. I have updated the question with more information. Let me try your suggestion... :)

Comment: @AndreiDurnea I tried to install and got this - Successfully installed cocoapods-1.5.3
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.5.3
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds
1 gem installed

Comment: Does pod init work now?

Comment: @AndreiDurnea  No , shows the same error

Comment: Refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904810/6059313

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndreiDurnea I removed it & reinstalled it. Now it works ! :)

Comment: @SharadChauhan Thanks man. Removal & reinstallation made it work . :)

Comment: Most welcomed! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please install `cocoapods` into `/usr/local/bin` and not into `/usr/bin` with this command:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

And you should remove `cocoapods` before reinstalling: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

Comment: Thanks a lot man ....  It did work !!! I removed it and reinstalled it. Now its fyn :)

Answer (score 5):

You will probably solve this by installing the cocoapods gem into your current RVM-installed Ruby:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Since you are using RVM, there is no need to ever use `sudo` for any commands to install or change anything about your Ruby. When installing gems with `sudo gem install ...`, you are installing it into your system's Ruby installation instead of your RVM Ruby. This can then cause issues in the interaction between the RVM environment and the system Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Re installation helped me. Also thanks for the edit ..... it looks better now. :)

Answer (score 4):

I run into same error.
But uninstall and `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` did NOT work for me.

So I tried `rvm list rubies` and found out there's a warning:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.3'.
```

I've no idea what's going on so I followed this issue: [Warning! PATH is not properly set up, usually this is caused by shell initialization files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968580/warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-usually-this-is-caused-by-shell-initializa)

I did `rvm reset` & `rvm version`. The warning disappeared.

Then I run `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

This fixed my problem. Post it here in case some one run into similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**$sudo gem install cocoapods**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried to install and got this - Successfully installed cocoapods-1.5.3 Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.5.3 Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds 1 gem installed

Answer (score 0):

If you already has cocoapods installed and you recently deleted or moved the current folder just try re-enter into the path again. Maybe terminal does not know where you are any more. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What did work for me I set 'command line tool path' in xcode preferences and was able to install missing pods

Answer (score -1):

Please install cocoapods into /usr/local/bin and not into /usr/bin with this command:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: this does not work