# Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin is not at first place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, path, rvm

### Description

I am still getting the warning given below when I run `rvm -v`.

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.7.3
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
rvm 1.29.12-next (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
```

Although it seemed to me that RVM was successfully installed after `type rvm | head -1` returned `rvm is a function`.

### Steps to reproduce

I am using OS X for Apple Silicon - Mac M1, with bash as the default shell.
So, I installed default Ruby and installed Git, to reinstall them with homebrew.

**.bash_profile**

```
source ~/.profile
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

**.zshrc** if required.

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

**.bashrc**

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

and trying to install RVM following the steps listed below:

1. Install gpg using Homebrew to verify the integrity of the RVM installer.
   `brew install gpg`
   `brew doctor`
   And got `Your system is ready to brew.` which seems that I successfully added it.
2. Download the public key for the RVM installer.
   `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`
   and I am not getting any error, also seems to be successful.
3. To install RVM and the latest version of ruby and rails, which is probably a good idea, use the following command.
   `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enable`
   which is returning the following (seems to be OK):

```
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.12.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Fri Jan 15 23:46:22 2021 +05
gpg:                using RSA key 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: Good signature from "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 7D2B AF1C F37B 13E2 069D  6956 105B D0E7 3949 9BDB
GPG verified '/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.12.tgz'
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.mkshrc /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.profile /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.bashrc /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.profile /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.bash_profile /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/ is complete.

Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate
```

4. As a final step to verify that everything went well.
   `type rvm | head -1`
   which is returning `rvm is a function`.
   And this confirms that installation was successful as per [rvm.oi documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#troubleshooting-your-install).

### Expected behavior

When I run `rvm -v`, at least, I was expecting that there will not be the warning shown on the top **Description section**, which also briefly given below:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin is not at first place.
```

### Actual behavior

I think I included it above in **Steps to reproduce** section.

**Debug mode**:

I have tried the solutions given in this [issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2050) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17972565/14103174), but I still couldn't resolve this `$PATH warning`.

### Environment info

Running `rvm info` returns:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.7.3
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.

ruby-2.7.3:
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

  system:
    uname:        "Darwin Sarvars-MacBook-Air.local 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Tue Oct 12 18:33:38 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.8~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64"
    name:         "OSX"
    version:      "11.6"
    architecture: "arm64"
    bash:         "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin20)"
    zsh:          "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)"
    remote_path:  "osx/11.6/arm64"
    xcode:        ""

  rvm:
    version:      "1.29.12 (latest)"
    updated:      "13 minutes 4 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm"
    autolibs:     "[enable] Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X)."

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.7.3p183"
    date:         "2021-04-05"
    platform:     "arm64-darwin20"
    patchlevel:   "2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d"
    full_version: "ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [arm64-darwin20]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3"
    ruby:         "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3:/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/sarvarkhalimov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

*Thanks in advance!* I had created an [issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5147) on rvm repo as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4306#issuecomment-591677076) which states the following:

> I encountered a similar error using Mac OS 10.14.6 and RVM 1.29.9.
>
> For me the issue was resolved by moving the following code in my `.bash_profile` to the bottom of the file:
>
> ```
> # RVM can encounter errors if it's not the last thing in .bash_profile
> export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to path for scripting (to manage Ruby versions)
> export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"
> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
> ```